# Understanding metaclass and inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

I have some confusion regarding meta-classes.

#### With inheritance

```
class AttributeInitType(object):

   def __init__(self,**kwargs):
       for name, value in kwargs.items():
          setattr(self, name, value)

class Car(AttributeInitType):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Car, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    @property
    def description(self):
       return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.color, self.year, self.make, self.model)

c = Car(make='Toyota', model='Prius', year=2005, color='green')
print c.description
```

#### With meta class

```
class AttributeInitType(type):
   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       obj = type.__call__(self, *args)
       for name, value in kwargs.items():
           setattr(obj, name, value)
       return obj

class Car(object):
   __metaclass__ = AttributeInitType

   @property
   def description(self):
       return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.color, self.year, self.make, self.model)


c = Car(make='Toyota', model='Prius', year=2005,color='blue')
print c.description
```

As above example is not useful as practically but just for understanding,

I have some questions Like,

1. What is the difference/similarity between a meta class and inheritance?
2. Where should one use a meta class or inheritance?

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you can do it without metaclasses, don't use metaclasses.

Comment: If you have to ask whether or not you need a metaclass, you don't need a metaclass.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of **what is a metaclass**. It is a discussion of **metaclass vs inheritance**.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

1) What is use of metaclass and when to use it?

Metaclasses are to classes as classes are to objects. They are classes for classes (hence the expression "meta").

Metaclasses are typically for when you want to work outside of the normal constraints of OOP.

2) What is difference/similarity between metaclass and inheritance?

A metaclass is not part of an object's class hierarchy whereas base classes are. So when an object does `obj.some_method()` it will not search the metaclass for this method however the metaclass may have created it during the class' or object's creation.

In this example below, the metaclass `MetaCar` gives objects a `defect` attribute based on a random number. The `defect` attribute is not defined in any of the objects' base classes or the class itself. This, however, could have been achieved using classes only.

However (unlike classes), this metaclass also re-routes object creation; in the `some_cars` list, all the Toyotas are created using the `Car` class. The metaclass detects that `Car.__init__` contains a `make` argument that matches a pre-existing class by that name and so returns a object of that class instead.

Additionally, you'll also note that in the `some_cars` list, `Car.__init__` is called with `make="GM"`. A `GM` class has not been defined at this point in the program's evaluation. The metaclass detects that a class doesn't exist by that name in the make argument, so it creates one and updates the global namespace (so it doesn't need to use the return mechanism). It then creates the object using the newly defined class and returns it.

```
import random

class CarBase(object):
    pass

class MetaCar(type):
    car_brands = {}
    def __init__(cls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict):
        super(MetaCar, cls).__init__(cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)
        if(not CarBase in cls_bases):
            MetaCar.car_brands[cls_name] = cls

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        make = kwargs.get("make", "")
        if(MetaCar.car_brands.has_key(make) and not (self is MetaCar.car_brands[make])):
            obj = MetaCar.car_brands[make].__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            if(make == "Toyota"):
                if(random.randint(0, 100) < 2):
                    obj.defect = "sticky accelerator pedal"
            elif(make == "GM"):
                if(random.randint(0, 100) < 20):
                    obj.defect = "shithouse"
            elif(make == "Great Wall"):
                if(random.randint(0, 100) < 101):
                    obj.defect = "cancer"
        else:
            obj = None
            if(not MetaCar.car_brands.has_key(self.__name__)):
                new_class = MetaCar(make, (GenericCar,), {})
                globals()[make] = new_class
                obj = new_class(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                obj = super(MetaCar, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj

class Car(CarBase):
    __metaclass__ = MetaCar

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s>" % self.description

    @property
    def description(self):
        return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.color, self.year, self.make, self.model)

class GenericCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["make"] = self.__class__.__name__
        super(GenericCar, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Toyota(GenericCar):
    pass

colours = \
[
    "blue",
    "green",
    "red",
    "yellow",
    "orange",
    "purple",
    "silver",
    "black",
    "white"
]

def rand_colour():
    return colours[random.randint(0, len(colours) - 1)]

some_cars = \
[
    Car(make="Toyota", model="Prius", year=2005, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="Toyota", model="Camry", year=2007, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="Toyota", model="Camry Hybrid", year=2013, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="Toyota", model="Land Cruiser", year=2009, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="Toyota", model="FJ Cruiser", year=2012, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="Toyota", model="Corolla", year=2010, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="Toyota", model="Hiace", year=2006, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="Toyota", model="Townace", year=2003, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="Toyota", model="Aurion", year=2008, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="Toyota", model="Supra", year=2004, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="Toyota", model="86", year=2013, color=rand_colour()),
    Car(make="GM", model="Camaro", year=2008, color=rand_colour())
]

dodgy_vehicles = filter(lambda x: hasattr(x, "defect"), some_cars)
print dodgy_vehicles
```

3) Where should one use metaclass or inheritance?

As mentioned in this answer and in the comments, almost always use inheritance when doing OOP. Metaclasses are for working outside those constraints (refer to example) and is almost always not necessary however some very advanced and **extremely dynamic** program flow can be achieved with them. This is both their strength and their **danger**.

Comment: Thanks dilbert .. gr8 explanation 
This difference can be noted from :
with metaclass, issubclass(Car,AttributeInitType) returns -> False

Comment: That's no worries. I don't know why this was marked as duplicate; the other thread didn't really say WHY nor give a compare/contrast to ordinary OOP practices.

Comment: in python 3 your example going into "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"