# The call order of python3 metaclass

Tags: python, metaclass

I am in confusion when trying to understand the order that `metaclass` creates a class instance. According to this **diagram** ([source](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#id28)), [image]

I type the following **codes** to verify it.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(self):
        print("Meta __call__")
        super(Meta, self).__call__()

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        print("Meta __new__")
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, kwargs)

    def __prepare__(msc, name, **kwargs):
        print("Meta __prepare__")
        return {}

class SubMeta(Meta):
    def __call__(self):
        print("SubMeta __call__!")
        super().__call__()

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        print("SubMeta __new__")
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, kwargs)

    def __prepare__(msc, name, **kwargs):
        print("SubMeta __prepare__")
        return Meta.__prepare__(name, kwargs)

class B(metaclass = SubMeta):
    pass

b = B()
```

However, the result seems not like this follow.

```
SubMeta __prepare__
Meta __prepare__
SubMeta __new__
Meta __new__
SubMeta __call__!
Meta __call__
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For those arriving at this question trying to understand meta-classes in Python, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801344/understanding-metaclass-and-inheritance-in-python instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite @torek's lenghty answer, with a lot of *other* details on class creation, what you brought together to this question is mostly correct.

The only thing that is wrong in your code, which propably puzzled you is that te class you call `Meta` have to be itself the  **metaclass** from `SubMeta` and not its parent.

Simply change `Submeta` declaration to:

```
class SubMeta(type, metaclass=Meta):
    ...
```

(No need for it to inherit from "Meta" as well - it can derive only from `type`. It is otherwise though to think of a customization to `type.__call__` that would be usefull at the same time for creating instances of your classes (that is when `SubMeta.__call__` is called), and your classes themselves (`Meta.__call__` called))

Here is another, shorter example I just typed at the terminal. Sorry for the naming inconsistencies, and for being less complete - but it shows the main point:

```
class M(type):
    def __call__(mmcls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("M's call", args, kwargs)
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

class MM(type, metaclass=M):
    def __prepare__(cls, *args, **kw):
        print("MM Prepare")
        return {}
    def __new__(mcls, *args, **kw):
        print("MM __new__")
        return super().__new__(mcls, *args, **kw)

class klass(metaclass=MM):
    pass
```

Upon processing the `klass` body, Python output was:

```
MM Prepare
M's call ('klass', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'klass'}) {}
MM __new__
```

## Moreover

As you can see from this, with a meta-meta class it is possible to customize the call order and parameters to the metaclass `__init__` and `__new__`, *but* there are still steps that can't be customized from pure-Python code, and would require native calls to API's (and possibly raw object structure manipulation) - that are:

- One can't control the call to `__prepare__`
- One can't control the call to `__init_subclass__` on the created classes
- One can control when descriptors' `__set_name__` are called

The last two items take place after meta-meta's `__call__` return, and before resuming the flow to the module where the class module is.

Answer (score 6):

#### The trick, identified

**Update 2:** Based on behavior, the fact that `M0.__call__` is called below *must* be a side effect of [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cd449806fac1246cb7b4d392026fe6986ec01fb7/Python/bltinmodule.c#L214) in `builtin__build_class` in the CPython source (`Python/bltinmodule.c`).

In order to define a class that has a metaclass, we call the metaclass's `__prepare__`, `__new__`, and `__init__` as usual.  This creates a class—in the example below, `Meta`—that is callable, but its internal `PyFunction_GET_CODE` slot points not to *its own* `__call__` but rather to its metaclass's `__call__`.  Hence if we call `Meta()` (the metaclass object), we invoke `M0.__call__`:

```
print("call Meta")
print("Meta returns:", Meta('name', (), {}))
print("finished calling Meta")
```

produces:

```
call Meta
M0 __call__: mmcls=<class '__main__.Meta'>, args=('name', (), {}), kwargs={}
Meta __new__: mcs=<class '__main__.Meta'>, name='name', bases=(), attrs={}, kwargs={}
Meta __init__: mcs=<class '__main__.name'>, name='name', bases=(), attrs={}, kwargs={}
Meta returns: <class '__main__.name'>
finished calling Meta
```

In other words, we see that `Meta` acts like `type`, but it (rather magically and not very well documented) invokes `M0.__call__`.  This is no doubt due to looking up `__call__` in the class's type, rather than in an instance of the class (and indeed there is no instance except for the one we're creating).  This is in fact the general case: it falls out of the fact that we call `__call__` on the *type* of `Meta`, and the type of `Meta` is `M0`:

```
print("type(Meta) =", type(Meta))
```

prints:

```
type(Meta) = <class '__main__.M0'>
```

which explains where this comes from.  (I still think this should be emphasized in the documentation, which also should describe the constraints on metaclass typing—these are enforced in [`_calculate_winner` in `Lib/types.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cd449806fac1246cb7b4d392026fe6986ec01fb7/Lib/types.py#L125-L140) and, as C code, [in `_PyType_CalculateMetaclass` in Objects/typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cd449806fac1246cb7b4d392026fe6986ec01fb7/Objects/typeobject.c#L2318-L2352).)

#### Updated original answer

<s>I don't know where your diagram came from, but it's wrong.</s> **UPDATE:** You can in fact have a metaclass for your metaclass; see [jsbueno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53255735/1256452), and I've updated the example below.  New sentences / text are in **bold,** except for the final section describing my puzzlement at the apparent lack of documentation.

Your existing metaclass code has at least one error.  Most significantly, its `__prepare__` needs to be a class-method.  See also [Using the __call__ method of a metaclass instead of __new__?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6966772/1256452) and [PEP 3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/).  **And, to use a meta-meta-class, your metaclass needs to have a metaclass of its own, *not* a base class.**

[Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53191742/1256452) contains correct definitions.  But there are some unfortunate asymmetries between metaclass method arguments and class method arguments, which I'll illustrate below.

One other thing that may help: note that the metaclass `__prepare__` method is called *before creating any instances of class `B`:* it is called when `class B` itself is being defined.  To show this, here is a corrected metaclass-and-class.  I have also added a few more illustrators.  **I've added a meta-metaclass as well, based on jsbueno's answer.  I cannot find formal Python documentation on this, but I've updated the output below.**

```
class M0(type):
    def __call__(mmcls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("M0 __call__: mmcls={!r}, "
              "args={!r}, kwargs={!r}".format(mmcls, args, kwargs))
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta(type, metaclass=M0):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Meta __call__: cls={!r}, "
              "args={!r}, kwargs={!r}".format(cls, args, kwargs))
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        print("Meta __new__: mcs={!r}, name={!r}, bases={!r}, "
              "attrs={!r}, kwargs={!r}".format(mcs, name, bases, attrs, kwargs))
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)

    def __init__(mcs, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        print("Meta __init__: mcs={!r}, name={!r}, bases={!r}, "
              "attrs={!r}, kwargs={!r}".format(mcs, name, bases, attrs, kwargs))
        super().__init__(name, bases, attrs, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(cls, name, bases, **kwargs):
        print("Meta __prepare__: name={!r}, "
              "bases={!r}, kwargs={!r}".format(name, bases, kwargs))
        return {}

print("about to create class A")
class A(metaclass=Meta): pass
print("finished creating class A")

print("about to create class B")

class B(A, metaclass=Meta, foo=3):
    @staticmethod
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("B __new__: cls={!r}, "
              "args={!r}, kwargs={!r}".format(cls, args, kwargs))
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("B __init__: args={!r}, kwargs={!r}, ".format(args, kwargs))

print("finished creating class B")

print("about to create instance b = B()")
b = B('hello', bar=7)
print("finished creating instance b")
```

Now, let's observe what happens when I run this, and take each piece apart:

```
$ python3.6 meta.py
about to create class A
Meta __prepare__: name='A', bases=(), kwargs={}
M0 __call__: mmcls=<class '__main__.Meta'>, args=('A', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'A'}), kwargs={}
Meta __new__: mcs=<class '__main__.Meta'>, name='A', bases=(), attrs={'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'A'}, kwargs={}
Meta __init__: mcs=<class '__main__.A'>, name='A', bases=(), attrs={'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'A'}, kwargs={}
finished creating class A
```

To create class `A` itself, Python first calls the metaclass's `__prepare__`, delivering it the name of the class (`A`), the list of base classes (an empty tuple—it's called a list but is actually a tuple), and any keyword arguments (none).  As PEP 3115 notes, the metaclass needs to return a dictionary or `dict`-like object; this one does by just returning an empty dictionary, so we are good here.

(I don't print `cls` itself here, but if you do, you will see it is just `<class '__main__.Meta'>`.)

Next, having gotten a dictionary from `__prepare__`, Python **first calls the meta-meta `__call__`, i.e., `M0.__call__`, passing the entire set of arguments as the `args` tuple.**  It then populates the `__prepare__`-supplied dictionary with all the attributes for the class, passing this as the `attrs` to the metaclass `__new__` and `__init__`.  If you print the `id` of the dictionary returned from `__prepare__` and passed to `__new__` and `__init__` you will see they all match.

Since class `A` has no methods or data members, we see only the magic `__module__` and `__qualname__` attributes here.  We also see no keyword arguments, so now let's move on to creating class `B`:

```
about to create class B
Meta __prepare__: name='B', bases=(<class '__main__.A'>,), kwargs={'foo': 3}
M0 __call__: mmcls=<class '__main__.Meta'>, args=('B', (<class '__main__.A'>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'B', '__new__': <staticmethod object at 0x800ad0a58>, '__init__': <function B.__init__ at 0x800ad2840>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x800a749d8: empty>}), kwargs={'foo': 3}
Meta __new__: mcs=<class '__main__.Meta'>, name='B', bases=(<class '__main__.A'>,), attrs={'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'B', '__new__': <staticmethod object at 0x800ad0940>, '__init__': <function B.__init__ at 0x800ad27b8>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x800a745b8: empty>}, kwargs={'foo': 3}
Meta __init__: mcs=<class '__main__.B'>, name='B', bases=(<class '__main__.A'>,), attrs={'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'B', '__new__': <staticmethod object at 0x800ad0940>, '__init__': <function B.__init__ at 0x800ad27b8>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x800a745b8: Meta object at 0x802047018>}, kwargs={'foo': 3}
finished creating class B
```

This one is rather more interesting.  Now we have one base class, namely `__main__.A`.  Class `B` also defines several methods (`__new__` and `__init__`) and we see them in the `attrs` dictionaries passed to the metaclass `__new__` and `__init__` methods (which, remember, are just the now-populated dictionary returned by the metaclass's `__prepare__`).  **As before, the passing-on happens through the meta-meta-class `M0.__call__`.**  We also see one keyword argument throughout, `{'foo': 3}`.  In the attribute dictionary, we can also observe the magic `__classcell__` entry: see [Provide __classcell__ example for Python 3.6 metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41343263/1256452) for a short description as to what this is about, but to be, er, *super*-short, it's for making `super()` work.

The keyword argument is passed to all three metaclass methods, plus that of the meta-meta-class.  (I'm not quite sure why.  Note that modifying the dictionary in any *metaclass* method does not affect it in any other, as it's a copy each time of the original keyword arguments.  **However, we *can* modify it in the meta-meta-class: add `kwargs.pop('foo', None)` to `M0.__call__` to observe this.**)

Now that we have our classes `A` and `B`, we can get on to the process of creating an actual instance of class `B`.  Now we see the metaclass's `__call__` invoked (not the meta-meta-class's):

```
about to create instance b = B()
Meta __call__: cls=<class '__main__.B'>, args=('hello',), kwargs={'bar': 7}
```

It's possible to change the `args` or `kwargs` passed on, but I don't; the sample code above winds up calling `type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` (through the magic of `super().__call__`).  This in turn calls `B.__new__` and `B.__init__`:

```
B __new__: cls=<class '__main__.B'>, args=('hello',), kwargs={'bar': 7}
B __init__: args=('hello',), kwargs={'bar': 7}, 
finished creating instance b
```

which finishes the realization of the new instance of class `B`, which we then bind to the name `b`.

Note that `B.__new__` says:

```
return super().__new__(cls)
```

so we invoke `object.__new__` to create the instance—this is more or less a requirement of all versions of Python; you can only "cheat" when you return a singleton instance (ideally, one that's non-modifiable).  It's `type.__call__` that calls `B.__init__` on this object, passing the arguments and keyword-arguments we passed it.  If we replace `Meta`'s `__call__` with:

```
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Meta __call__: cls={!r}, "
              "args={!r}, kwargs={!r}".format(cls, args, kwargs))
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

we will see that `B.__new__` and `B.__init__` are *never called:*

```
about to create instance b = B()
Meta __call__: cls=<class '__main__.B'>, args=('hello',), kwargs={'bar': 7}
finished creating instance b
```

This would, in effect, create a useless/uninitialized instance `b`.  It's therefore critical that the metaclass `__call__` method call the underlying class's `__init__`, usually by invoking `type.__call__` via `super().__call__`.  If the underlying class has a `__new__`, the metaclass should call that first, again usually by invoking `type.__call__`.

#### Side note: what [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) says

To quote section 3.3.3.6:

> Once the class namespace has been populated by executing the class body, the class object is created by calling `metaclass(name, bases, namespace, **kwds)` (the additional keywords passed here are the same as those passed to `__prepare__`).

This explains the call to `Meta.__call__` when creating `b` as an instance of class `B`, but not the fact that Python first calls `M0.__call__` before calling `Meta.__new__` and `Meta.__init__` when creating classes `A` and `B` themselves.

The next paragraph mentions the `__classcell__` entry; the one after that goes on to describe the use of `__set_name__` and `__init_subclass__` hooks.  Nothing here tells us how or why Python calls `M0.__call__` at this point.

Earlier, in sections 3.3.3.3 through 3.3.3.5, the documentation describes the process of determining the metaclass, preparing the class namespace, and executing the class body.  This is where the meta-metaclass action *should* be described, but isn't.

Several additional sections describe a few additional constraints.  One important one is 3.3.10, which talks about how special methods are found via the object type, bypassing both regular member attribute lookups and even (sometimes) a metaclass getattribute, saying:

> Bypassing the `__getattribute__()` machinery in this fashion provides significant scope for speed optimisations within the interpreter, at the cost of some flexibility in the handling of special methods (the special method *must* be set on the class object itself in order to be consistently invoked by the interpreter).

**Update 2: This is really the secret of the trick: the special `__call__` method is found via the type's type.  If the metaclass has a metaclass, the meta-meta-class provides the `__call__` slot; otherwise the type of the metaclass is `type`, so that the `__call__` slot is `type.__call__`.**

Comment: Despite your lenghty answer, and rather usefull information on the process of class creation, you did not touch the subject of the "meta-meta-class" call method, the OP is in doubt about. In fact, there is only a simple mistake in the OP's code - and the diagram posted in the question is actually correct.

Comment: While I'm not sure whether I agree with jsbueno about what the mistake in the questioner's code is, I agree that you seem to have missed the meta-metaclass aspect, and that the diagram in the question is correct.

Comment: @jsbueno: interesting. I haven't seen this described elsewhere. Indeed, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html makes no mention of it while describing how regular metaclasses work.

Comment: @user2357112: indeed, testing shows it works—but there seems to be no hint of this in any documentation I can find.

Comment: Thanks a million for your detailed answer, I learned a lot. The diagram comes from the blog — [understanding-python-metaclasses](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#putting-it-all-together).  Just like mentioned by **jsbueno**,  Meta-metaclass should  `class SubMeta(type, metaclass=Meta):` rather than `class SubMeta(Meta):`.

Comment: Well - it is not documented but for Python's principle of "least surprise". In an ordinary instance the calls to its class' `__new__` and `__init__`  are orchestrated by the metaclass `__call__`, and this is simply the same mechanism wen that instance is a an instance of `type`. It is even possible to not run different code in type's  `__call__`  for instantiating classes and ordinary instances (although IIRC there are some customizations there).