# Can I avoid the ```metaclass=``` when I define an inherited class?

Tags: python, metaclass

I would like to have a custom metaclass that **looks like** the definition of a `TypedDict`.

When one declares a new `TypedDict` we write something like this:

```
from typing import TypedDict

class MyClass(TypedDict, total=False):
  pass
```

However, when I declare a metaclass, it looks like this:

```
class MetaSerial(type):
  def __new__(pls, name, bases, act, exclude: list[str] = [], custom: list[str] = []):
    dct["_exclude"] = exclude
    dct["_custom"] = custom
    return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class Serial(metaclass=MetaSerial, exclude=["value"], custom=["terminals"]):
  pass
```

So, the million dollar question is: is there a way for me to get rid of the annoying **metaclass=** and use something like:

```
class Serial(MetaSerial, exclude=["value"], custom=["terminals"]):
  pass
```

Comment: Make all your actual classes subclasses of `Serial`. They'll inherit its metaclass.

Comment: See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802762/1491895)

Comment: Thank you, Barmar!

I can see that my post was not so clear... The goal is that every time I create a new subclass of MetaSerial, I can specify my own "exclude" and my own "custom". Similar to what I do with TypedDict and its "total". Is that possible WITHOUT using the thing "metaclass=" similarly to what we do with TypedDict?

Comment: You don't make subclasses of metaclasses unless you're making a new metaclass. Superclasses and metaclasses serve two completely different purposes.

Comment: So you make a representative class using the metaclass, then everything else is a subclass of that.

Comment: Another approach is to use a decorator, like dataclasses.

Comment: `TypedDict` is itself is a *function* that's given a `__mro_entries__` attribute to allow it to be used as a base class. When called, it returns a class created by `_TypedDictMeta`.

Comment: (I'm not entirely sure *why* `TypedDict` is defined that way, but Barmar's suggestion is still correct if you really want to use a metaclass.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid metaclasses where possible (every metaclass you define is a potential conflict with another metaclass). All you need here is a base class with an appropriate `__init_subclass__` method.

```
class SerialBase:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, exclude: list[str] = None, custom: list[str] = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if exclude is None:
            exclude = []

        if custom is None:
            custom = []

        cls._exclude = exclude
        cls._custom = custom

class Serial(SerialBase, exclude=["value"], custom=["terminals"]):
    pass
```